# Can you explain what is happening on this oscilloscope? (sequential counter circuit)

Tags: circuit-design, oscilloscope, sequential-logic

I built an up/down counter circuit and set the frequency on this oscilloscope to 1Hz. Can someone explain what the (blurred sorry) image represents?
Is the blue or the yellow line the clock?
Which is 'high'/'low'?

[image]

Comment: The oscilloscope won't be supplying a clock; it will measure the voltages of the parts of the circuit that the probes are attached to and plot them together on the screen.  What are the probes attached to?  Show us a schematic of the circuit.  It looks like the yellow is a divided-down version of the blue signal.

Comment: please post clear photo of the screen that fills more than 95% of the photo ... your picture is blurry and the screen fills only 25% ... that scope may even do digital screenshots

Answer (score 1):

> Is the blue or the yellow line the clock?

Yes.

> Which is 'high'/'low'?

Assuming positive logic, 'high' is the upper line, and 'low' is the lower line of each trace.

If you compare the two traces you will see that each time the blue line goes from high to low the yellow line changes (from low to high and high to low alternately). This suggests the yellow signal is the first output of the counter, and the blue signal is the clock ( which is 'clocking' on its trailing / negative edge).

However the blue signal could be one of the outputs of a multistage counter, and the yellow signal the output of the next stage. You should know which by what is in the circuit and where you put the scope probes.